# How effective is the ProxyGambit at allowing access to the internet without revealing true location and IP?

Tags: proxy, anonymity

I'm very interested in purchasing or manufacturing this device on my own and maybe using it in conjunction with Tails/Tor:

https://samy.pl/proxygambit/

According to the site:

> ProxyGambit is a simple anonymization device that allows you to access
>   the Internet from anywhere in the world without revealing your true
>   location or IP, fracturing your traffic from the Internet/IP through
>   either a long distance radio link or a reverse tunneled GSM bridge
>   that ultimately drops back onto the Internet and exits through a
>   wireless network you're no where near.
>
> While a point to point link is possible, the reverse GSM bridge allows
>   you to proxy from thousands of miles away with nothing other than a
>   computer and Internet with no direct link back to your originating
>   machine.
>
> A high speed (150Mbps+) link is available with direct line of sight
>   from 10km+ away, or if further away, a 2G GSM connection produces a
>   reverse TCP tunnel serializing a shell into the device accessible from
>   anywhere in the world via the Internet or GSM. Either method proxies
>   your connection through local wifi networks near the device, shielding
>   and making it more difficult to determine your true location, IP and
>   identity.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be sold anywhere online and it hasn't been discussed online since 2015.

My apologies for asking so many questions, but there appears to be no info on the actual workings of this anonymizing device, apart from a few stories in the media. For all those with some technical aptitude:

Has this device been extensively field-tested? Have there been any recent technological developments that have improved on the device? Does the device do what it says it does? And how would this compare to a directional long-distance wifi antenna to bypass need for an ISP and conceal physical device location? Would it be more or less secure or anonymous?

Comment: Your specific questions about the device should really be asked of the developer. The link provides multiple methods of contacting him.

Comment: ProxyGambit isn't "sold". It's a combination of a variety of off-the-shelf devices with a simple script to handle incoming connections. As such, not much will change or need to be changed except for updated versions of the individual components.

Comment: @schroeder I'm curious as to whether anyone else has used this device and whether they could provide some feedback on its effectiveness as an anonymizer. Apparently the ProxyGambit is a more technologically sophisticated device than the earlier ProxyHam, upon which it was meant to improve. The ProxyHam project was eventually shut down, some say because of government coercion.

Answer (score 1):

From the ProxyGambit website:

> This is an insecure, bare bones proof of concept. The fragmentation of data through alternate mediums is a useful and effective concept and those interested in privacy, anonymization, or deanonymization should explore this area further. Entropy is both gained and lost with these methods and many risks are involved when deploying any system of this nature.

It is *not* meant to be used as-is, but as a starting point for further research. It does not bring any new ideas to the table and in fact does not even use existing secrecy techniques for wireless devices, such as spread spectrum communication to provide LPI/LPD (Low Probability of Interception/Detection).